# MediaRecorder#prepare raise "java.lang.IllegalStateException"

Tags: java, android

here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/eba690ccfb3d4bcd150de9d2f037a227), I just use following code:

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir() + "/try.mp4");
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

how to make it work?

**update**

I use genymotion to test my code

Comment: Please provide the little bit more code and full error message.

Comment: @amasiddawadeyar it's all code, I put it in myActivity#onCreate

Comment: Please, post the logcat for the exception

Comment: Please post logcat message

Comment: do you shutdown the previous recorder?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" / >
```